# How does Tensorflow works

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow.
I am looking to get some help in understanding what is the minimum I would need to setup and work with a TensorFlow system?
Do I really need to read through the Tensorflow website documentation to understand the whole work process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basics of tensorflow is that first we create a model which is called a computational graph with tensorflow objects then we create a tensorflow session in which we start running all the computation. 
To install in windows ,I found this webpage [Installation of tensorflow in windows](http://developercoding.com/tensorflow/)
To learn more about tensorflow ,you also see [tensorflow guide](http://developercoding.com/tensorflow/basics.php).
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

YES YOU SHOULD!

Here is an easier version of tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-introduction-machine-learning-tutorial/

Easier and funnier version: [How to Make a Tensorflow Neural Network (LIVE)](https://youtu.be/qVwm-9P609I)